# Wait for ASPX page to render before releasing thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, threadpool

I am writing a library which writes something into the database for temporary use (use only once) and then gets removed (its strange, but there is a certain implementation necessary for this ). For this I am trying to execute a thread which writes in the data into the database, waits for the page to finish loading and then releases to finish executing, removing the record. I am not sure how to apprach this. One way is to make the thread sleep but then I am risking either not allowing enough time or the thread might still be running after the page has finished doing everything else. Is there a way to tie this into the page thread so I can release my thread right after it finishes? What are some, if any, approaches to something like this? Because this is a library I would much rather not have another programmer call a function at the end of his page code to remove the record; its messy and easily forgotten.

Comment: Have a look at this, it may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: few things you shouldn't use custom threads in asp.net application so i suggest you to insert/update db onload then delete onunload every thing in win service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use threads for some other reason (i.e. educational) consider using Application events for that - you can listen [AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx) and [ReleaseRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.releaserequeststate.aspx) or similar pair depending on your needs and perform your database operations. Check [application lifecicle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to see all events and order of them.

[How to: Create ASP.NET Application-Level Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzzh56s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you create another thread? Write the record in the Load event and delete it in the Unload event.

Comment: " Because this is a library I would much rather not have another programmer call a function at the end of his page code to remove the record; its messy and easily forgotten."

Comment: You can create a BasePage class and handle the record in the load and unload events. You only have to force the library user to inherit your class, although he might not like it.